# UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes sometime doesn't get the right Bytes

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to encode a UTF-8 text into a German Latin encoding.

```
UnicodeEncoding unicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] bytes = unicodeEncoding.GetBytes(text);
```

The problem sometimes the Method encodes `ä` with `ä(0x00e4)` or with `a(0x0061)` and `"(0x0308)`.

Comment: are you looking for [UTF8Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: `UnicodeEncoding` is for UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: "I wanna encode a UTF-8 text" - wait... text is text is text; as an implementation detail, .NET uses UTF-16 for `string`, but that doesn't matter; it makes no sense to "encode UTF-8", since UTF-8 is **already** encoded. If you want to encode a `string` as UTF-8, then sure, that makes  sense, but you would use `Encoding.UTF8` (aka `UTF8Encoding`), not `UnicodeEncoding` (which is one of the 16 variants)

Comment: As for the choice of whether to encode ä as a direct code-point vs via combining characters; that is largely up to the encoder and the input data; either can be valid

Comment: If i use UTF8Encoding instead if UnicodeEncoding its the same Problem.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you actually want to do here. The code you show encodes a `string` value as UTF16. Also, your claim that for a given character you sometimes get 0x34 and sometimes get 0x61 is implausible; for a given encoding and character, you will always get the same value. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, along with a precise description of what the code does, and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: In UTF-8 there are two possibilities to encode an `ä` character: One as single character and one as [combined character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). Both variants you have encountered are valid.

Comment: I want to Convert the Text into a UTF-8 Byte Array and delete after that chars from it by the ByteCode. I just want to have 1 of the 2 variants.

Comment: What you get depends on the input. If you want to get only one output you have to format the input accordingly.